# Why does this return two sets of data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

I have built my firs full stack app that uses a react front end to communicate with a graphql server and surface data up from a mongoDB. When I look at the app from front end it looks like I am making two calls and return two sets of data (actually the same set twice).

Here is what I see in the dev tools console...

[image]

It looks to me like the first two are calls out and the last two are the data returns. If you look on the right, those are all to do with line 17 of BookList.js which is this...

```
    console.log(this.props);
```

and this is the full code of that file....

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

const getBooksQuery = gql`
    {
        books {
            name
            id
        }
    }
`;

class BookList extends Component {
    render(){
      console.log(this.props);
        return(
                      <div>
                <ul id="book-list">
                    <li>Book name</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default graphql(getBooksQuery)(BookList);
```

I am calling that BookList component with this code...

```
// components
import BookList from './components/BookList';

// apollo client setup
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql'
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <div id="main">
                <h1>Ninja's Reading List</h1>
                <BookList />
            </div>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am unsure why I am getting dbl calls or if that is the expectation. Any guidance at all is appreciated.

Comment: Check in the network tab in the inspector tools to see if the request is called twice.

Comment: I see one fetch so do you know why it looks like twice in the console?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using strict mode?

Comment: @SonOfNye The `console.log` runs every time the component it is in re-renders so that's why you see it in the console twice.